# iPad 1, iOS 5.1.1 jailbroken with redsn0w, works great, but since inetutils installed, getting network timeouts. How to adjust/fix?

Tags: ipad, networking, jailbreak, ios5.1

I have done a jailbreak on old iPad 1, using redsn0w.  Has worked really well. Installed OpenSSH, and I can use Putty on Windows or SSH on Linux to login to my iPad, and of course, pscp or scp to migrate files to/from using Windows or Linux.  Installed DOSbox (using DOSpad.deb file), and it works fine.  But there was no "ping" on the basic jailbreak version, so I installed "inetutils", which provides all the GNU inet stuff (ping, ftp, inetd, rlogin, telnet) and then found "arp iconfig netstat route traceroute" in Network Commands.  This makes an old tablet very, very useful.  Really fine stuff, but I notice now that the iPad network access times out quickly.  This is new behaviour, since the Cydia "inetutils" install. If I set the iPad down, after a few minutes, I cannot ping it from any machine on my LAN.  I could, before I installed the networking utilities.  Maybe a security feature?  If so, can I back out the network stuff, and just have ssh access, and have it *not* timeout?   I want to to be "alive" all the time.

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with installing inetutils - it's just a bunch of executables. It sounds like your iPad just goes to sleep. If you leave any iOS device with screen turned off for a couple of minutes it will turn off the WiFi and go to sleep. For it be "alive" all the time you have to install special software like insomnia.

Comment: Thx for response, and yes, I am familiar with inetutils.  My key point is that *before* I installed the Cydia package version of inetutils for jailbroke iPad, the network access did *not* go to sleep.  Sure, the screen would sleep, but the iPad would remain network-aware, as long as it had power and was on.  This behaviour changed after I installed inetutils, from Cydia source repo "Telesphoreo".  If I query "ifconfig en0", i notice one of the parameters is "SMART".  I suspect this might be the issue. I wish to have the original behaviour, where the device remains network aware at all times.

Comment: I described original behaviour - it supposed to go to sleep as you describe. if you didn't change anything yourself inetutils can't do anything to change that simply by being installed. It's already normal behaviour. You probably just didn't observe it before. But it doesn't matter anyway, you're describing completely normal behaviour for iOS devices no matter jailbroken they're or not. Download insomnia or something like that to fix it, there's no other solution.

Comment: I don't wish to be rude, but that is not correct. Perhaps you are unfamiliar with what happens when one runs the "jailbreak".  Device behaviour is changed by the installed software. I have identified the "cydia.log" and the "dpkgl.log", which shows the new and different libraries and utilities installed, and other re-configuration to network prgms which has occured. When I determine what has changed, and how to back it out, I will post that information here.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it.  When you jailbreak an iPad ver. 1, running iOS 5.1.1, using Redsn0w, the initial install of the code that provides root access does not include standard inetutils.  The original behaviour of the iPad 1, if configured with static ip values, meant that if was on, and the wifi was enabled, it would respond to a "ping", even if the screen was "asleep".

This ping-response was useful for diagnostic purposes.  Initial install of the jailbreak code did not change this behaviour.  But I could not "ping" out from the iPad to other machines since there was no ping.exe available, even after the jailbreak (this contrasts to Blackberry Playbooks, which had a "ping" utility, and would also respond to pings, even if "asleep").

So I downloaded the "inetutils" package from Cydia source Telesphoreo, and that provide a ping.exe, which could be used in console mode on the iPad.  It worked fine, and is a very useful program.

But, if you set the iPad aside, after about 5 minutes, it would time out.  It appears the wifi transmit function is just shutdown, and response to "ping" is explicitly disabled.

After much research and experiment, I've determined that you can re-activate the iPad "ping" response - remotely - by sending it an SSH query.  Example:

[your_id@Linbox ~]$  ssh mobile@xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa

where xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa is your IPV4 address,
assuming you have configured your iPad with a static ip value.  (I own a couple of class C ip ranges, so I have been using these for many years, in my work).  The two defined userids after jailbreak are "mobile" and "root".

The new behaviour appears after you download and install all the newer "inetutils" utilities, and the "Network Commands" utilities, from the Telesphoreo source repository.

This behaviour change is actually a pretty good idea, as it discourages inappropriate usage of ping, and probably also saves battery life. But it is a change from previous operational characteristic. Another fellow went down this same rabbit-hole, and documented the solution on the "jailbreakqa.com" site, url below:

http://www.jailbreakqa.com/questions/192379/persistent-wi-fi-when-locked

Hope this info is useful.
Curious to see this query downvoted..  Lemmie say, having this old iPad run as a full-blown remote-accessable Linux box is very useful.  Once jailbroken, one can scp files back and forth, install custom computational code locally, and basically have all your office on a small, thin, light tablet in a little briefcase.  Most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting post... just what i am looking for. I use an ipad 1/16g/3G for a display on my kitchen wall for displaying domotica info. This works well and using ssh i can have it turn on, display something and turn off. 
I got myself another ipad 1/16gb wifi only and this one had the sleeping wifi problem. My first thought was that it had to do with the 3g chip.. that maybe this keeps the ipad alive while the other one goes to sleep.  The 3G model doesn't have inetutils installed and still doesnt go to sleep. So there seems some merrit to my line of thoughts. 
I installed the inetutils on the wifi only ipad and it seems like this solved this trick. I can ssh into it just fine.. even when it is in sleep mode. Thanks for your update. 
The link in your post doesn't work anymore..